# Return value if four columns match

Tags: excel

I have four columns from sheet1 and five columns from sheet2:

```
Year |Region   |Treatment | Height |    Cost    
1941 |  L      |    B     |    20  |    14.00    
1941 |  L      |    B     |    25  |    14.00    
1941 |  L      |    B     |    30  |    16.00
```

I'd like to return the value from column "cost" only if the values in columns "year", "region", "treatment", and "height" from this sheet matches the same columns in sheet1.  I can do it for two columns but I can't figure out how to extend that for four.

Thank you

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  Can you clarify?  What exactly do you want to match among the four columns?  From your example data, I don't see how any of the columns would match each other in a given row.  Also show what you have tried for two columns, this will help.

Comment: You can create a concatenated column joining all four columns (with e.g. ~ as separator) then perform a vlookup on the concatenated column.

Comment: @jmstoker Sorry, I edited my original question.  I have 4 columns from sheet1 that I'd like to matchup with the columns listed above, and if they match, return the cost value corresponding to the row that matches all columns.

Comment: @TimWilliams Hmm, ya that would work!  Thanks.  Is there another formulaic way just out of curiosity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to what Tim Williams suggested without the vlookup

This formula will display the Cost from Sheet1 or blank if the entries are not identical on both sheets.  Keep in mind it is case sensitive.

On Sheet2 in the Cost Cell (E2) use the following formula

```
=IF(UPPER(Sheet1!A2)&Sheet1!B2&Sheet1!C2&Sheet1!D2 = A2&B2&C2&D2, Sheet1!E2, "")
```

Then you can just drag the formula down.

If you want the formula to be case insensitive wrap each cell in UPPER()

```
=IF(UPPER(Sheet1!A2)&UPPER(Sheet1!B2)&UPPER(Sheet1!C2)&UPPER(Sheet1!D2) = UPPER(A2)&UPPER(B2)&UPPER(C2)&UPPER(D2), Sheet1!E2, "")
```